# Is there a way to remove the Amplitude default events logs from the console on initialization?

Tags: amplitude-analytics

I'm using `Browser SDK 2.0` to track some [default events](https://www.docs.developers.amplitude.com/data/sdks/browser-2/#tracking-default-events). I also have my `logLevel` set to `None`. For the most part I'm not seeing logs shown. However, on initializing Amplitude it always spits out a log in the console saying what I'm tracking as default. For me it's `Page Views`, `Sessions`, & `File Downloads`. Is there a way to remove this default events log? I would like the console to not include any output.
[image]